# Vim spell checking latex's newcommand definition

Tags: vim, spell-checking, vim-plugin

My problem is simple and I hope the solution too: vim-spell plugin doesn't colorize the incorrect words in `\newcommand`'s definition in LaTeX files:

```
 \newcommand{\mycommand}{Helllo World}
```

The `Helllo` will not be red. When I delete the parentheses around `Helllo world` it's marked as a bad word.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve a problem related with spelling in latex files and I got help in the vim_use group. Please read the messages in 
[google groups interface](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vim_use/qPMuFerx86k/discussion) to get the full details.

Try adding the following to your ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim file:

```
syn region texMyCmdSpell matchgroup=texStatement
      \ start='\\newcommand{.*{' end='}$'
      \ contains=@Spell
      \ containedin=texCmdBody
```

This seems to work for me. The start pattern is just defined by a new command, the end pattern by `}` followed a a newline.

Comment: Thanks your answer but I think it will not the solution. As I see on your link discuss about how can disable builtin spell-checking on some cases (in environment's parameters, etc.). I need to enable spell-checking. Or do you have an idea?

Comment: The procedure is similar. You use the plugin HILINKS (the link is provided in one of the messages), and you identify the region that way. The only other difference is that while in my case I wanted to disable spelling for some regions I would use `@NoSpell` and in your case you want the oposite so you will use `@Spell`.

Comment: Hm, maybe understand. But I've a one more question: how can I define `end`? Your (if `skeept` on link == `skeept` here) solution on link assumes that in `tabular`'s parameters isn't `}`. But in my declaration via `newcommand` can be `}` without end of declaration. (if there's a solution, sorry, I'm not a vim-expert)