# force vim to check spelling of text within arguments of \newcommand

Tags: vim, spell-checking, tex

I would like to customise the vim native spelling mechanism so that it be forced to check for  bad words within the *entire* arguments of `\newcommand`

Specifically my problem is that using an English dictionary, the bad words *"wellcome"* and *"fiendly",* when used among the arguments of `\newcommand`, are not highlighted by the syntax rules, such as for example here:

```
\newcommand{\Greetings}[0]{ 
wellcome, this is your fiendly receptionist.
}
```

Running the command`echo synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name")`  one can tell that the environment or region where my bad words are located is`texCmdBody`, therefore the following [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553342/vim-spell-checking-latexs-newcommand-definition) should in principle work, specially when used together with `syntax spell toplevel`:

```
syn region texMyCmdSpell matchgroup=texStatement
\ start='\\newcommand{.*{' end='}$'
\ contains=@Spell
\ containedin=texCmdBody
```

This fix works, but it breaks down too easily.  It does work in  simple cases, but in general it stops working too early. It is as if the above definition of the end of the `texCmdBody region` were not sufficiently robust. I say this  because it stops finding bad words well before the last brace indicating the  end of `\newcommand`

Would anybody with more knowledge of vim syntax suggest an improvement of this fix? I have tried modifying it without success.

Alternatively, it is possible that all this be the result of bad use of `\newcommand` on my part. Typically I put the entire content of a beamer slide within a `\newcommand`, so that it can later be inserted wherever I want it, or sometimes I use `\newcommand` to  define problems for an exam.  But this might be bad practice. Is there a better TeX technique for having moveable blocks of text?